# How to display fetch data inside the table

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

How to get fetch data inside the react-native table here ?
When i tried to fetch data, the table display empty with this codes, so where and what to do for get the data from API and display in the table in react native.

```
getData() {
  fetch('https://www.lampmonitor.com/lampmonitor/api/auth/web/lampControls?projectId=595&pageSize=50')
    .then(responce => responce.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({ 
        tableData: data
      });
    });
}

render() {
  const state = this.state;
  const { tableData } = state;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
        <View>
          <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#C1C0B9'}}>
            <Row
              data={state.tableHead}
              widthArr={state.widthArr}
              style={styles.header}
              textStyle={styles.text}
            />
          </Table>
          <ScrollView style={styles.dataWrapper}>
            <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#C1C0B9'}}>
              {tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
                <Rows
                  key={index}
                  data={rowData}
                  widthArr={state.widthArr}
                   style={[
                     styles.row,
                     index % 2 && {backgroundColor: '#F7F6E7'},
                   ]}
                  textStyle={styles.text}
                />
              ))}
            </Table>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `getData()`? How have you initialised your state? What is the shape of the API response?

Comment: okay if i use to get data useEffect for fetch from the api the how to display in the table? suppose   useEffect(() => {
     fetch("https://www.lampmonitor.com/lampmonitor/api/auth/web/lampControls?projectId=595&pageSize=50", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  }, []);

Comment: You cannot use hooks in class based components. Also, you didn't answer any of my three questions

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to do it using React hooks.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

You have many errors and I think you need to brush up on the differences between Class components and Functional components using React Hooks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TableComponent;
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const TableComponent = () => {

  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      fetch('https://www.lampmonitor.com/lampmonitor/api/auth/web/lampControls?projectId=595&pageSize=50')
      .then(responce => responce.json())
      .then(data => {
        setTableData({data});
      });
    }

    getData();
}, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
        <View>
          <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#C1C0B9'}}>
            <Row
              data={tableData.tableHead}
              widthArr={tableData.widthArr}
              style={styles.header}
              textStyle={styles.text}
            />
          </Table>
          <ScrollView style={styles.dataWrapper}>
            <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#C1C0B9'}}>
              {tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
                <Rows
                  key={index}
                  data={rowData}
                  widthArr={tableData.widthArr}
                   style={[
                     styles.row,
                     index % 2 && {backgroundColor: '#F7F6E7'},
                   ]}
                  textStyle={styles.text}
                />
              ))}
            </Table>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: i am having an error here which is a Render Error - undefined is not a function (near '...tableData.map...')

Comment: what should i do to solve it?

Comment: for the function do i need to create another .js file or i can use it anywhere in table component file,Sir?

Comment: Render Error - undefined is not a function (near '...tableData.map...')                           getting this Error by using table component.